# I could not find the starting point and if I get the time then how can I get the velocity?

Tags: calculus

A particle moves along the x axis. Its moving function is given by x=6t+8.5t². What is the acceleration?

Comment: Why can't you answer this?  Where is your difficulty? Do you know what a particle moving is?  Do you know what a moving function is?  Do you know how to find the acceleration from a moving function?  Is there any difficulty with *this* moving function?  So.... where are you having trouble?

Comment: Why is your title question entirely different and has nothing to do with the question in the body?

Comment: What is $x''(t)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acceleration is the second derivative of the moving function.
You have the first derivative which is x' = 6 + 17 t
The second derivative is then x'' = 17, so the acceleration is 17

That's for the question in the text, but I don't actually get what you're asking in the title. Which starting point are you searching?

The velocity is the first derivative, so 6 + 17t
If you have a certain instant t in time, you can put your t in 6 + 17t and get the velocity in that instant.